# Problema com acentuação ao exportar dados do Sql Server para Excel

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Tenho o seguinte código dentro de um botão responsável por realizar a exportação dos dados da minha tabela para o excel.

```
    string caminho = "c:\\caminho";

        // criar um arquivo para escrever

        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(caminho))

        {
            string conn = @"Server=server;Database=base;Trusted_Connection=True;";

            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conn);               

            string sql = " Select * from CLIENTE";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);

            try

            {

                //abre a conexão e gera o datareader

                cn.Open();

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                // percorre o datareader e escreve os dados no arquivo .xls definido

                while (dr.Read())

                {

                    sw.WriteLine(dr["NOME"].ToString() + "\t" + dr["ENDERECO"].ToString() + "\t" + dr["CEP"].ToString() + "\t" + dr["BAIRRO"].ToString() + "\t" + dr["CIDADE"].ToString() + "\t" + dr["UF"].ToString() + "\t" + dr["TELEFONE"].ToString());

                }

                //exibe mensagem ao usuario

                MessageBox.Show("Arquivo " + caminho + " gerado com sucesso.");

            }

            catch (Exception excpt)

            {

                MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);

            }

        }
```

Os dados estão sendo exportados normalmente, o problema é que as palavras que contém caracteres especiais estão vindo desconfiguradas, creio que seja alguma configuração de `Encoding` mas não sei aonde realiza-la. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Jorge, você pode utilizar uma função no SQL-SERVER para remover acentuação ou caracteres especiais nos campos que você considera problema. Dá uma olhada no link abaixo e veja se te atende.

https://www.dirceuresende.com/blog/como-remover-acentuacao-e-caracteres-especiais-de-uma-string-no-sql-server/

Comment: Jorge, uma opção seria inserir um globalization sobre a aplicação. Sugiro que leia este [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hy4kkhe0(v=vs.71).aspx). Colocarei uma solução que talvez venha a te ajudar

Comment: `using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path,append, Encoding.Default))` https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Text_Encoding_

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que isto possa te ajudar.

Em seu App.Config (no caso de ser winforms), insira dentro de configuration a seguinte tag:

`<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <globalization uiCulture="pt-BR" culture="pt-BR" enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>`

Segue o [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hy4kkhe0(v=vs.71).aspx) para um melhor entendimento sobre esta solução e umas informações a mais sobre [culture Info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.71).aspx)